# Possible ways of making a common insert data function for whole project in asp.net using Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am wondering how can I avoid writing cmd.Parameter.addwithvalue again and again for all pages.In short something like a generic insert function. I am not using Entity framework so regular generic function of adding entities won't help.

Till now I have tried:

```
public string AddCampus(Campus objCampus)
    {
                //string Params = "@Activity,@Name,@PhoneNo,@Email,@Logo,@StatusId,@CountryId,@CityId,@StateId,@DistrictId,@ClientId,@Pincode,@AddressLine1,@AddressLine2,@Area,@Street";
                //string Values = "Add" + ',' + objCampus.Name + ',' + objCampus.PhoneNo + ',' + objCampus.Email + ',' + objCampus.Logo + "," + objCampus.StatusId + ","+objCampus.CampusAddress.CountryId + "," + objCampus.CampusAddress.CityId + "," + objCampus.CampusAddress.StateId + "," + objCampus.CampusAddress.DistrictId + "," + objCampus.ClientId + "," + objCampus.CampusAddress.Pincode + "," + objCampus.CampusAddress.AddressLine1 + "," + objCampus.CampusAddress.AddressLine2 + "," + objCampus.CampusAddress.Area + "," + objCampus.CampusAddress.Streat;
                //return  Connection.CommandExecuteNonQuery(Params, Values,true, "sprCampus");
    }
```

I made this and it works but i have just coommented that.This was the implementation:

```
   public static string CommandExecuteNonQuery(string Parameters,string Values,bool IsStoredProcedure,string command)
    {   string[] Parameter = Parameters.Split(',');
        string[] Value = Values.Split(',');
        string s_Message = "";
        if (Parameter.Count() < Value.Count())
        {
            s_Message = "Number of Paramters Supplied is less than Number of Values Supplied.";
            return s_Message;
        }
        else if (Parameter.Count() > Value.Count())
        {
            s_Message = "Number of Values Supplied is less than Number of Parameters Supplied.";
            return s_Message;
        }
        else
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            for (var i = 0; i < Parameter.Count(); i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(Parameter[i], Value[i]);

            }
            cmd.CommandText = command;
            if (IsStoredProcedure)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            string saveSuccess = string.Empty;
            int execute = 0;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlConStr))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    execute = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (execute > 0)
                    {
                        s_Message = "Record Saved";
                    }
                    else
                        s_Message = "Operation Failed";



                }
                catch (Exception excp)
                {
                    s_Message = excp.Message;
                }

            }
        }
            return s_Message.ToString();







    }
```

So am just looking for a better solution than this.

Comment: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: replacing one line with other won't be helpful. I want a global insert function and that should be adaptive as different pages have different insert paramters

Answer (score 1):

I had the same idea a while back. The following probably isn't the most optimized solution however I think it's pretty good.

```
    // Parameter used for StoredProcedure
    private class Parameter
    {
        public Parameter(string name, object value)
        {
            Name = name;
            Value = value;
        }

        public readonly string Name;
        public readonly object Value;
    }

    // Executes a given stored procedure with parameters and returns a SQLDataReader
    private static SqlDataReader ExecuteDataReader(string name, SqlConnection dbConnection, List<Parameter> parameters = null)
    {
        if (parameters == null)
            parameters = new List<Parameter>();

        using (var command = new SqlCommand(name, dbConnection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
        {
            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Name, parameter.Value);

            return command.ExecuteReader();
        }
    }

    // Executes a given stored procedure with parameters
    private static void ExecuteNonQuery(string name, SqlConnection dbConnection, List<Parameter> parameters = null)
    {
        if (parameters == null)
            parameters = new List<Parameter>();

        using (var command = new SqlCommand(name, dbConnection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
        {
            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Name, parameter.Value);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Even though its not perfect for my requirement.It is better to use than mine one for sure.Well done buddy

Comment: Thanks, I think it's pretty good. It's easily flipped to using sql command text as well which is why I like it. Simply removed the '{ CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }' line and perhaps change the name of the variable 'name' to 'sql' or something